# div won't go below adjecent div?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little issue here. This is my HTML.

```
<div class="one">
</div>

<div class="two">
   <ul class="ulclass">
     <li>DASDA</li>
     <li>QWEQW</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.one{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}

.two{
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.ulclass{
list-style-type: none;

margin:0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.ulclass li{
width: 500px;
padding: 10px;
overflow: auto;  
float: left;
}
```

My problem is that these divs are next to each other and not above the other.

It looks like this.

http://oi57.tinypic.com/2lm5e1i.jpg

I want the green one to be down the black one. I have tried a lot of things and I can't do it.

I forget, these divs are inside another DIV which is a container

here the css:

```
.rost{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #fff;
padding: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0  0 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  display: flex;  
  display: -webkit-box;

}
```

Here is the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/aemgm73z/

Comment: In the link i post you can see i have two divs, one black and one green.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I can't access that link. The code you posted doesn't suggest any green

Comment: There's no reason in your css that the divs would not act as wanted. Have you tried inspecting them (right click on div and click "inspect element") to see if there's other additional css rules that are being applied?

Comment: Dont worry, they are two divs that seem to be floated left but they are not. i just want to be down.

Comment: @NachoDawg Yes i have inspected the elements, and still cant make them be down. i dont know what its happening, i have changed the display and the positions and nothing. Maybe the <li> float is affecting...

Comment: remove the `display:flex` and `display: -webkit-box` property from your parent div.

Comment: Yes you got it. Now they are down. the problem now is that my container wont show. woops... either way thank you from there i can work. @VineetKaushik

Comment: I agree with @NachoDawg, there doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: I agree @GurminderSingh the problem was in the container div as Vineet Kaushik say

Comment: @VineetKaushik forget what i say i can see the container div, Thank you you got the answer.

Comment: Glad to know @Daniel. Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped.

Comment: @VineetKaushik I cant see where, anyway, you solve that problem but now the second div appers not to be inside the container div, any suggestions? http://jsfiddle.net/aemgm73z/1/ Tellme where to mark your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel it seems you've put the `<li>` elements within the `<a>` elements which is why they are spilling out of the divs. The child divs ARE in the parent divs but because you've enclosed the links the otherway round the divs aren't expanding to wrap around them

Comment: You can see this point by assigning a fixed height, say 1000px to `.lista` div and upon inspection find that `.rost` does enclose both the divs.

Comment: @VineetKaushik Thank you, you have helped me a lot. Blessings to you my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `display: -webkit-box` and `display: flex` from  your parent container.

As far as the second div goes it seems you've put the `<li>` elements within the `<a>` elements which is why they are spilling out of the divs. The child divs ARE in the parent divs but because you've enclosed the links the other way round the divs aren't expanding to wrap around them

You can see this point by assigning a fixed height, say 1000px to .lista div and upon inspection find that .rost does enclose both the divs.

Swapping the `li` and `a` tags should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

try adding `clear:both;` to `.two` class

```
.two{
  clear:both;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: not working either. maybe the container div is the problem. thank you anyway.

Comment: Can you see if there is any issue with CSS code, as I don't see anyother issue with the code you have posted. `clear:both;` is just a handle to move the div to next line, if that is not doing what is required then I hope there is some issue with CSS code. Check if you have missed any `;` at the end of class definition

Comment: I have updated and posted a JSFIDDLE where you can see the problem. Thank you. i dont have any syntax problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any specific reason to include `float: left` into your css? After removing that, things are working as you expect.

```css
.one{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}

.two{
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: green;
}

.ulclass{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin:0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.ulclass li{
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
</div>

<div class="two">
   <ul class="ulclass">
     <li>DASDA</li>
     <li>QWEQW</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: didnt work, i uppdated my problem maybe the div containter is affecting them. thank you anyway.

Comment: @Daniel. Have you tried running code snippet given here?

Comment: Yes i did it worked. The thing is my code wont. See my post again i uploaded a JSFIDDLE so you can se the problem. Thank you for your time and support.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `disply:block` and `margin-top:0px` property from your style

Comment: didnt work mate. thank you anyway, i updated and gived more info.

Comment: @daniel then place this code in between these two divs <div style="clear:both;"></div>

Comment: dont working either. seems the problem isnt the float.... im going to upload the code so you can see it live. wait please.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display:block;` to your `.one` style, this will make the green div bump down onto the next line.

Comment: How does that not work? If it doesn't work, then there's something seriously wrong with either your code, or your CSS styling.

Comment: They were both blocks, it was the display in the container div as you may see in the main answer. Thank you anyways, every answer was helpfull to me. i know this may be rookie stuff but im learning. Thank you!